# How can I add topics / hashtags to my Dart / Flutter package on pub.dev?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages, pub.dev, dart-packages

[image: Screenshot of a package from pub.dev]

I discovered on pub.dev that you can add topics / hashtags to your Dart / Flutter package on pub.dev. However, I couldn't find any [documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/publishing) on how to add them to my own package.

How can I add them to my own package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add topics / hashtags to your package by adding them to your `pubspec.yaml`, like:

```yaml
topics:
 - camera
 - image-picker
 - files
 - files-selection
```

See this example: https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/e7d812cefce083fa09762d25cd42303737d05b9f/packages/image_picker/image_picker/pubspec.yaml#L47C1-L47C1

To browse through all topics on pub.dev, visit: https://pub.dev/topics

Documentation about topics: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#topics